# Key values of 'key' and 'type' in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am given to understand that the words `type` and `id` are reserved words in json schema. Is there any way to set these as keys in json schema? Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
"id": {
    "type": "string"
},
"featureType": {
    "type": "string"
},
"type": {
    "type": "string"
}
```

I have tried validating this using a number of tools (including [here](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/)). Googling around yields no suggestions either. Any help much appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you pasted above will most probably work. `"type"` and `"id"` are reserved keys, but they have special meaning only in case their corresponding value is a string. Since the values are objects in your case, there is no problem. I'm not 100% sure if the json schema spec explicitly states this, but this is how implementations work usually.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think the problem I was having was that they weren't inside a `properties` object. i fixed that now and it validates